# MainWindow in Utility Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, xcode4

I am following the `CoreDataBooks` Sample Code in a `Utility Application`, and so far, I have been able to display a `tableView` without a `Navigation bar` on top. How can I get the `Naviagation bar` to display at the top? The `TableView` is in the `FlipsideViewController`.

I think that the problem is that the sample code has a `MainWindow.xib` and a `Utility Application` does not. How can I create a `MainWindow.xib` and only have the `Navigation Controller` on the `FlipsideViewController`?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that you write must have a `UIWindow` as that is the superview of everything.

In order to have a `UINavigationController` display with your tableView you will have to do this:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myFlipSideViewController] ;
```

Then the same way you are showing your FlipSideViewController show your Navigation Controller instead.

Comment: I do not think I understand your point. In my FlipsideViewController, there is no UIWindow. There is only a UIWindow in my MainViewController. There is also no XIB for MainWindow as the sample code does. Lastly, where would I place your code?

Comment: @Ahan Malhotra Yes that is correct there is only one UIWindow per application, you only need one to place your first view, you do not need any other UIWindows. You would place your that code below your FlipsideViewController instantiation, and place that object in the initwithrootviewController, then instead of showing your flipsideViewController show the navigationController.

Comment: I would place the code in my FlipsideViewController's viewDidLoad? When I do that, I get the error `Unexpected interface name 'FlipsideViewController':expected expression`

Comment: @Ahan Malhotra no not in the viewDidLoad of your Controller, but on the code that shows your flipsideViewController, which I think in this case is a button push, that is where would put it.

Comment: I still get the same error as before `Unexpected interface name 'FlipsideViewController':expected expression`